# Usage on farewell remark

Tags: nouns

I found several forms of farewell remarks like these:

```
Goodbye
Good-bye
Good-by
Bye
Bye-Bye
```

Are these remarks equivalent in both written and spoken English ?

Comment: The proper spelling is "Usage"

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Good bye", "Bye", "Bye bye"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2626/good-bye-bye-bye-bye)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

More or less, they're all equivalent. Let's break it down for each version:

`Goodbye`

This is the most standard/conventional, and a perfectly formal version.

`Good-bye`

A more old-fashioned version of `goodbye`, also acceptable, though less standard.

`Good-by`

Alternative (rather less common) spelling of `good-bye`.

`Bye`

A shortened version of `goodbye`; perfectly acceptable, though slightly less formal.

`Bye-Bye`

Means the same thing; the least formal of all versions, rather colloquial.